# Query with multiple WHERE for single column

Tags: php, sql, select

I need to select all the values where a single column matches multiple values. At one point I saw something like the following but it is not working for me. Is this correct or do I need to link these values with AND?

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE AGE = ( 20, 21, 22 )
```

Also im doing this in a php script and getting my values in an http post so if anyone can point me in the direction of a good example that would be great. THanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `IN`

```
SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE AGE IN ( 20, 21, 22 )
```

and it is the same as

```
SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE AGE =  20 OR
      AGE =  21 OR
      AGE =  22
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Does this work with only 1 value as well. Ex: WHERE AGE IN ( 20 ) ?

Comment: @jgelderloos definitely yes :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to use IN, but be careful:

if the field or the values are not some numeric format, you have to quote each value:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD IN ('a','b','c')
```

Also, if you are using numeric fields, be sure that each value is not null. This will fail:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD IN (1,,3,4,5)
```

This will throw an error.